# How to convert string date (yyyy) in to Date format in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How to Convert string date into DateTime and add days?

```
 string strYear= "2020";
 DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(strYear, "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 datetime.addDays(10);
```

Comment: `AddDays` method returns new value.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
    string strYear= "2020";
        DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(strYear, "yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        datetime = datetime.AddDays(10);
```